# Why is lwjgl missing from the classpath when doing gradle run?

Tags: classpath, gradle, lwjgl

Can anyone help me get gradle to correctly include lwjgl? It seems like the dependency is getting ignored because when I do a gradle run java can't find the library.

I have the following maven file:

```
apply plugin:'groovy'
apply plugin:'application'

mainClassName = 'com.martz.zimplatformer.Game'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    groovy group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '1.8.6'
    compile group: 'org.lwjgl.lwjgl', name: 'lwjgl', version: '2.+'
}
```

When I do a gradle run, I get the following stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1758)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
    at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the error is due to java not being able to find the native libraries. There is a lwjgl-platform dependency in maven, but just adding it does not point the jvm to the correct native libraries. I got it working by adding a hard-coded path to the native libraries on my machine after downloading the native libraries from the lwjgl website:

```
run {
    jvmArgs = '-Djava.library.path=/path/to/native/macosx'
}
```